# Handwriting Recognition to database

Tags: android, windows, handwriting, handwriting-recognition

I'm working on some language learning software and I want to use Windows and Samsung's existing handwriting recognition with in my program for the user to make calls to a database (a list of commands) that I'm going to create. I have the slightest idea on where to begin or even how this would work. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search google. narrow down you question.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung provides Pen as part of their [Mobile SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk#pen). I haven't used it myself but the documentation says it contains a text recognition engine. However, it seems you not only get the recognition engine but have to use the whole package.

Comment: That's what I mean. I don't even know where to start learning something like this. This is what I want to happen. You use either your mouse or a tablet pen to write down a word. The program checks to see if the word is correct or incorrect. If correct the desired task is complete, if not the task fails.